# Are servlet threads and Connector threads the same?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have my Tomcat configured like this:

```
<Connector port="9080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" maxThreads="200" redirectPort="9443" />
```

Which means that Tomcat can process 200 concurrent requests on port 9080 as stated [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation).

Are those threads the same threads that execute the servlet's `service()` method on a request?

Comment: I would even extend statement and say - not only just the servlet's `service()` method, in fact, any http request that comes on 9080, for resources like images, js, jsp, css etc) uses the thread from the same thread pool(200 in your case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are.

You can see it yourself by implementing a simple servlet and printing/returning the thread name. The thrad name would probably be like `http-{connector-type}-{port}-exec-{threadNumber}`